# An html tag whose ID is having JSRendered Value, its value reading in the jquery script is not happening?

Tags: jquery, jsrender

am using JSRender in my application.

```
<html> 
<body> 
    {{for Comments}}  
        <input id="id_{{:CommentId}}" type="hidden" value="-1" />
        <textarea id="cmt_{{:TopicId}}" ......... />
    {{/for}}
</body>
</html>
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function () {

  //The below code gets executed / works fine.
  $('#cmt_{{:TopicId}}').bind('keyup keydown paste', function (e) {
    //my logic        
  });

  //This code doesnot work fine, instead of -1, it gives undefined.
  var rankAction = $("#id_{{:CommentId}}").val();
});        
</script>
```

i want the `rankAction` variable to give `-1`, whereas it returns `undefined`, why is it so?

Is it simply because `id` containing JSRendered value within them cant be read in Script coding?

Then why is the other part i.e. `cmt{{:TopicId}}` returning a value ?

Where is it wrong?

Comment: can you tell what does console prints

var id = "id_" + {{:CommentId}};
console.log(id);

or may be provide some fiddle

Comment: @vipulsharma: it wont allow such code in <Script>, rather it only allows this way, var id = "id_{{:CommentId}}" whose result is as id_. i.e. {{:CommentId}} is empty.

Comment: that means the selector is not generated correctly. Make the selector as desired first.

Comment: @vipulsharma:in html the selector i.e. the Input is getting generated properly at runtime, for example it will be like <input id="id_1234" .../>,  but the same is not read below in <script>.

Comment: I am not sure why it is happening but you can try setTimeout(function() {var id = "id_{{:CommentId}}";console.log(id)},30);

Comment: can you post the complete markup and javascript code as they are generated at runtime? My guess is that the CommentId variable is not accessible outside the loop

Comment: I don't see any calls to render the template.  Your example is too incomplete.  The document ready function is *not* executed inside jsrender.  I don't see how any part of the code is doing what you believe it is doing.

Comment: @pedz: am not sure whatz confuzing you. Please eloborate your expections so that i can explain more if required.

Answer (score 1):

To stack overflow folks: I apologize for making this an "answer" but the comments are not powerful enough to describe my questions.

@ismail baig:  A jsrender template is called such as this:

```
// Render the template with the movies data and insert
// the rendered HTML under the "movieList" element
$( "#movieList" ).html(
    $( "#movieTemplate" ).render( movies )
);
```

Note the pattern is some template.render(datalist) where the template can be defined using:

```
<script id="movieTemplate" type="text/x-jsrender">
    <div>
        {{:#index+1}}: <b>{{>name}}</b> ({{>releaseYear}})
    </div>
</script>
```

`#movieList` is just an element.  `movies` is a javascript array.  I don't see those three items: the template, the data list, nor the call to render the template in your example.

For reference, look at this [page](http://borismoore.github.io/jsrender/demos/demos.html) and do a view source to see the code, template, and usage.